# Change button name after successful insertion

Tags: jquery, ajax

After a users clicks on the submit button and the data has been sent to the browser, i want the button to be disable and changed. i've tried on my own to make it work. but its not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {


             $(".btn-style").click(function(){
        $(this).val('Inserted');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    data = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(".btn-style").val('Loading').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      data: data
    }).success(function() {


      $(".btn-style").val('Inserted');
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: it works perfectly for both firefox and chrome but the issue is, the buttons are nested so when i click on one it affects all of the rest. but i want it one by one

Comment: we need your html form. so that we can help you in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {
            $(".btn-style").val('Inserted').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is the button a `<button>` or an `<input type="button">`?

Comment: try `.attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: ok, it worked in firefox but not chrome. and the field are nested so when i click on one it changes all to inserted

Comment: it would help a lot if you'd share your html or even better create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the code of click event, like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calls/insert_fryd.asp",
            data: data
        }).success(function() {
            $('.btn-style').val('Inserted').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```